# Getting rid of Persistent SIGABRT error

Tags: objective-c, build

I keep getting the SIGABRT error with my app.  I've tried re-downloading my entire developer profile certificates and provisioning certs etc and still no change. I've also played with changing architectures.  The activity log for my project when it crashes is below - any one know what's causing it?

```
[CODE]GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1708) (Fri Sep 16 06:56:50 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=i386-apple-darwin --target=arm-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys001
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-1268-71
Switching to remote-macosx protocol
mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none
[Switching to process 7171 thread 0x1c03]
[Switching to process 7171 thread 0x1c03]
Couldn't register sh.heather.reactionfree with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.(gdb) [/CODE]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this problem a few times. I'm not sure but it seems to occur for me when I continually build and run without stopping the previous build in the simulator. (I try to always press the `stop` button now)

**Things to try**

1. Sometimes this is fixed by just quitting the simulator and Xcode.
2. Sometimes I've had to do a full system restart.

So they may get you back on your feet quickly but I would also enjoy hearing the reason/fix from someone who knows more.

Comment: Hi.  No luck unfortunately - restarted phone, re-installed Xcode and rebooted and still no change.

Answer (score 0):

you must be having memory management issues,. just clean build it and then press analyze for any issues/ leaks and dead memory management problems... once all are cleared then your program functions as per your coding.

Comment: I did this and still no change - it showed "possible leaks", all in SDK's I'd used before without problem.